# Angular progress bar and timer (linked)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I am trying to add countdown timer into an AngularJS app (a small quiz)

That part is probably easy enough.. The catch is that I want a progress bar at the bottom of the page to sync up with the countdown timer (So the bar either increases or decreases as the timer runs out)

Not looking for a complete answer, just someone to point me in the right direction of to how to approach the task as I feel a bit clueless.

Once again, thank you in advance, kind Angular wizards!

Comment: I don't know if the two parts share the same controller, but if they don't you can use a service that will save the status of the both progress.

Comment: if you're using a $interval or $timeout for the timer, you can modify the currentValue of the progress bar in the same function.

Comment: you can totaly isolate both components, and make them communicate to each other via $rootScope.$on and $rootScope.$broadcast, so you can on every timer brodcast $rootScope.$boradcast('timer:increase'), and then inside progress bar $rooScope.$on('time:increase',function() { doSomething(); })